# Export to text file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I am working on exporting data to text file in rails.
I have got the required code here http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=37888.
But it is not supporting unicode chars like '\n'. 
How can I add support for this special chars in exporting data to text in rails application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite knowing what you are exporting, but if you are exporting the contents of a table, something like this will work

```
my_file = File.open("export.csv", 'w')

@fields = Field.all
@fields.each do |field|
  outpurstring = "id: " + field.id + "\t" + .... etc.
  my_file.puts outputstring     
end
my_file.close
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, but i have to export data in text template format. like id: 1234
     ----------
     Name: Test

Comment: OK, updated to use the txt format with strings. puts command automatically puts a new line at the end

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at how we can `read` / `write` to a `text file` with the help of a simple program:

```
# p027readwrite.rb  
# Open and read from a text file  
# Note that since a block is given, file will  
# automatically be closed when the block terminates  
File.open('p014constructs.rb', 'r') do |f1|  
  while line = f1.gets  
    puts line  
  end  
end  

# Create a new file and write to it  
File.open('test.rb', 'w') do |f2|  
  # use "\n" for two lines of text  
  f2.puts "Created by Gagan\nThank God!"
```

for more info check this **[Link](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/read_write_files.html)**